# NextJS app-dir error pages and CDN cacheing (AWS Cloudfront specifically)

Tags: caching, next.js, cdn, next.js13

How are we supposed to handle NextJS's new file/path based error files in conjunction with cacheing CDNs?

Specifically, I'm building a new website using the app route handling of Next 13 and generating content from a headless CMS. The initial content is all statically generated, and then new pages/posts are done with [Dynamic Route Segments](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes).

In my specific case, my CMS lets me define webhooks for content changes. Then, whenever content is modified/deleted/created I hit an API route that invalidates the Next cache, and sends an AWS invalidation command to CloudFront. So, 404 errors aren't a problem. It's totally OK for the error to be cached on CloudFront, because if I ever create that page, it will invalidate the CloudFront cache and the content will then be available.

However, if I hit an actual error — say, a server side error, as I happen to have just done — the CDN will cache the error "page" as the actual page.

So, to make ti real, my structure looks like this:

```
/app
    error.js
    global-error.js
    layout.js
    not-found.js
    /reflections
        error.js
        layout.js
        /[slug]
            error.js
            layout.js
            not-found.js
            page.js
```

If hitting [www.mysite.com/reflections/foo](http://www.mysite.com/reflections/foo) generates a 500 error, then what gets served is, effectively

```
<app/layout>
  <app/reflections/layout>
    <app/reflections/[slug]/layout>
      <app/reflections/[slug]/error />
```

and that whole things gets cached at the CDN. If the error ever recovers, then /reflections/foo will still get the error page until the cache expires.

How are we supposed to handle this?